Telerik UI issue executing Inline Script
I need to execute inline script of telerik UI in my web forms MVC application. I want to not include "unsafe inline " in CSP header. how can I do this? AS telerik official site they say "If CSP is enabled for a web application, which utilizes Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX, you have to add at least the unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline keywords"
When I include 'unsafe-inline' it works perfectly like below.
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", $"script-src 'self' http://10.78.138.207/BvsPanelNewV1/ 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'");
When I do not include 'unsafe-inline' it give me error to use either hash or nonce key. i use both nonce and hash but it not work for telerik UI controls.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX relies on inline scripts for functionality, which means full CSP compliance without unsafe-inline is not supported. As noted in the official Telerik documentation, adding unsafe-inline to your CSP header is necessary for these controls to work correctly:
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'self' http://10.78.138.207/BvsPanelNewV1/ 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';");

Using hashes or nonces isn’t practical here because the inline scripts are dynamically generated and unpredictable, as explained in this IIS Support Blog.
If avoiding unsafe-inline is critical, you might need to consider migrating to a framework with stricter CSP support.
